# Printing each element in stack to new line in text file

Tags: java, string-formatting

I cant seem to get each string element of the stack to print to a new line. I would like to be able to retrieve the data from this text file with another method that reads one line at a time. I have that method completed.

```
public Save(Stack<String> names, String fileName)
{
    try
    {
        File Test = new File("" + fileName + ".txt");
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(Test);

        while (names.empty() == false)
        {
            String output = names.pop();
            out.write(output);
        }
        out.close();
        VALID_SAVE = true;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a constructor, not a method...

Comment: Well yes, you are right. But this is the classes entire functionality.

Comment: Fair enough...though as a general rule, it's a bad idea to do real work in constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a newline after each `out()`:

```
String output = names.pop();
out.write(output);
out.write("\n");
```

And please:

```
while(!names.empty())
```

Also since `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException` and the exception handling is identical, the first `catch` clause is superfluous.

Comment: I have tried out.write("\n"); It does not work. But thank you for the other suggestions. I'm a bit of a newbie :P

Comment: @ChrisNevoraski I just tried it and it correctly prints new line after each element on the `Stack`. Or maybe I don't understand the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use system property which is line separator indepdent of OS out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"))